# How do I create a select all checkbox when I have an empty array as my checked.bind

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I have a table with checkboxes as the first column. I want to have a select all checkbox in the header. I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

```html
<template>
  <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><input type="checkbox" /></th>
          <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" checked.bind="selected" model.bind="site" /></td>
          <td>${site.id}</td>
        </tr> 
      </tbody>
    </table>  
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the very best way to solve this problem has three parts. We need to bind the `checked` attribute and the `indeterminate` attribute, and we need to handle the change event.

First, we want the checkbox to be checked whenever the `selected` array has all the items in the `items` array. So:

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked.bind="selected.length === items.length" />
```

This checks the checkbox whenever all items are selected, but checking the checkbox has no effect on the `selected` array yet.

Next, we want the checkbox to be indeterminate whenever `selected` array has some but not all items in the `items` array. So:

```html
<input type="checkbox 
  checked.bind="selected.length === items.length"
  indeterminate.bind="selected.length > 0 && selected.length < items.length" />
```

Now, the checkbox completely reflects the state of the `selected` array, but still has no effect on the `selected` array.

Finally, we can listen to the `change` event on the checkbox to update the `selected` array whenever the checkbox is checked or unchecked. I use an inline handler below, and in this handler `$event.target` is the checkbox itself.

```html
<input type="checkbox"
  checked.bind="selected.length === items.length"
  indeterminate.bind="selected.length > 0 && selected.length < items.length"
  change.delegate="$event.target.checked ? selected = items.slice() : selected = []" />
```

At this point, the checkbox is working perfectly. Checked is normally a two-way binding, but in our example above it is only operating one-way. We can make this small optimization:

```html
<input type="checkbox"
  checked.one-way="selected.length === items.length"
  indeterminate.one-way="selected.length > 0 && selected.length < items.length"
  change.delegate="$event.target.checked ? selected = items.slice() : selected = []" />
```

See this gist.run for a working example: https://gist.run/?id=61cc823708ff7f6ba195de9ff0353049

Note that I typically find it useful to create a custom element that encapsulates this behavior.

Comment: checked.delegate should be changed to change.delegate

Comment: i wrote up a full blog about the subject here: http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-checkboxes/